# Sort the age of 3 individuals

Tags: c, if-statement

```
/* to find the age of individuals according to youngest to oldest */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int age1, age2, age3, youngest, middle, oldest;
  {
    printf ("Enter the age of the first individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age1);
    printf ("Enter the age of the second individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age2);
    printf ("Enter the age of the third individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age3);
  }
  if (age1==age2==age3);
  {
    printf("All individuals have the same age of %d", &age1);
  }
  else
  {
    youngest = age1;

    if (age1 > age2)
      youngest = age2;
    if (age2 > age3)
      youngest = age3;

    middle = age1;

    if (age1 > age2)
      middle = age2;
    if (age2 < age3)
      middle = age2;

    oldest = age1;

    if (age1 < age2)
      oldest = age2;
    if (age2 < age3)
      oldest = age3;

    printf("%d is the youngest.\n", youngest);
    printf("%d is the middle.\n", middle);
    printf("%d is the oldest.\n", oldest);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error on line 21 which states that I have an 'else' with a previous 'if'. Any of the experts here can tell me where I went wrong? The display is also a little weird if I were to remove the 'else'.

Comment: The expression `age1==age2==age3` doesn't do what you think. It's equal to `(age1==age2)==age3` which means you are comparing the *boolean result* of `age1==age2` to `age3`.

Comment: you have problems on `if (age1==age2==age3);` - due to `;`, your `else` is alone

Comment: Rolled back. You are supposed to not change the question if that leaves an answer without context!

Answer (score 8):

In your code

```
 if (age1==age2==age3);
```

is horribly broken.

Two main points,

- An expression like `age1==age2==age3` is either

  - `0 == age3` , when `age1 != age2`
  - `1 == age3` , when `age1 == age2`

  none of which is you want.
- The `;` at the end of the `if` statement makes the next block unconditional.

At best, you can rewrite the same as

```
 if ( ( age1 == age2 ) && ( age2 == age3) ) { .... }
```

---

After that, in case of

```
  printf("All individuals have the same age of %d", &age1);
```

you don't need to pass the *address-of* the variable. This, in fact makes the statement very wrong, passing an incompatible type of argument to a supplied conversion specifier, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

less ifs if you use the variable

```
#define swap(a,b)    do { int c = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = (c);} while(0)
if (age[2] > age[1]) swap(age[2], age[1]);
if (age[1] > age[0]) swap(age[1], age[0]);
if (age[2] > age[1]) swap(age[2], age[1]);
```

---

or

```
if (age2 > age1) swap(age2, age1);
if (age1 > age0) swap(age1, age0);
if (age2 > age1) swap(age2, age1);
```