# Sorting the age of 3 individuals

Tags: c

```
/* to find the age of individuals according to youngest to oldest */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int age1, age2, age3, youngest, middle, oldest;

    printf ("Enter the age of the first individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age1);
    printf ("Enter the age of the second individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age2);
    printf ("Enter the age of the third individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age3);

    if ( ( age1 == age2 ) && ( age2 == age3) ){
        printf("All individuals have the same age of %d", &age2);
    }

    else (age1 != age2) && (age1 != age3) && (age2 != age3);{
        youngest = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
            youngest = age2;
        if (age2 > age3)
            youngest = age3;

        middle = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
            middle = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
            middle = age2;

        oldest = age1;

        if (age1 < age2)
            oldest = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
            oldest = age3;

        printf("%d is the youngest.\n", youngest);
        printf("%d is the middle.\n", middle);
        printf("%d is the oldest.\n", oldest);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Hi i changed my code but the display still shows a weird number when i input the same age for everyone. And how do i make it such that if everyone has the same age, then only the line saying all individuals have the same age of ___. Please do help me with this as its a graded assignment and im having trouble with this

All individuals have the same age of 63567321 is the youngest. 1 is the middle. 1 is the oldest.

Comment: `printf("All individuals have the same age of %d", &age2);` Remove `&` --> `printf("All individuals have the same age of %d\n", age2);`

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code properly, I personnally will not even attempt to read code presented like that. Then, this is not a question for SO but for your debugger.

Comment: Don't [REPOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939540/sort-the-age-of-3-individuals).

Comment: To be fair to the OP, despite the similar title, this is not actually a duplicate of the previous question. The original had bugs, which were pointed out in errors. OP tried to edit/update the original question with fixes for those errors, but this was rolled back because it changed the context of the answers. Presumably, this question is the update that he first tried to do as an edit on the original.

Answer (score 2):

Three main problems:

1. When equal ages, you are passing the pointer to integer not the integer itself to `printf()`
2. `else` statment does not have an `if'
3. **INDENTATION** - *does not effect the execution but is crucial in helping one find problems in the code much easier*

*Correct code:*

```
/* to find the age of individuals according to youngest to oldest */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int age1, age2, age3, youngest, middle, oldest;
    printf ("Enter the age of the first individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age1);
    printf ("Enter the age of the second individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age2);
    printf ("Enter the age of the third individual: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &age3);

    if ( ( age1 == age2 ) && ( age2 == age3) )
    {
    printf("All individuals have the same age of %d", age2);
    }

    else if ((age1 != age2) && (age1 != age3) && (age2 != age3))
    {
        youngest = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
        youngest = age2;
        if (age2 > age3)
        youngest = age3;

        middle = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
        middle = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
        middle = age2;

        oldest = age1;

        if (age1 < age2)
        oldest = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
        oldest = age3;

        printf("%d is the youngest.\n", youngest);
        printf("%d is the middle.\n", middle);
        printf("%d is the oldest.\n", oldest);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**-- EDIT**

Please note that in the above solution, if two of the ages are equal, the oldest and youngest ages are not printed. To fix this I would remove the if condition for the `else`, and include a check before printing the middle value. New else statment:

```
    else
    {
        youngest = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
        youngest = age2;
        if (age2 > age3)
        youngest = age3;

        middle = age1;

        if (age1 > age2)
        middle = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
        middle = age2;

        oldest = age1;

        if (age1 < age2)
        oldest = age2;
        if (age2 < age3)
        oldest = age3;

        printf("%d is the youngest.\n", youngest);

        // If two ages are equivalent, do not print middle
        if ((age1 != age2) && (age1 != age3) && (age2 != age3))
            printf("%d is the middle.\n", middle);

        printf("%d is the oldest.\n", oldest);
    }
```

Disclaimer: Although I have given the above solutions to keep the original code, I would prefer a more generic approach in the following way:

1. Create a method that sorts an array of integers: `sort(int *array, int size)`
2. Read the input ages into an integer array: `int ages[3]`
3. Pass the ages to the sort function: `sort(ages, 3);`
4. Print results from sorted array : `ages[0]`, `ages[1]`, `ages[2]`

This way the code is way more readable, and reusable..

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. As of now my class hasnt progressed to learning array so im using the really slow method as seen above. Thanks for the advice and help!!!!

Comment: My pleasure to be of help :) please mark answer as accepted if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like

```
if (age1>age2 && age1>age3) {
   oldest=age1;
   if (age2>age3)
       middle = age2;
       youngest=age3;
    } else {
        middle = age3;
        youngest=age2;
    }
 } else if (age2>age3) {
   oldest=age2;
   if (age1>age3)
       middle = age1;
       youngest=age3;
    } else {
        middle = age3;
        youngest=age1;
    }
} else {
   oldest=age3;
   if (age2>age1)
       middle = age2;
       youngest=age1;
    } else {
        middle = age1;
        youngest=age2;
    }
}
```